# How to exclude an appendix table from list of table?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a table in Appendix. It also shows in list of tables. How can I remove it?

I tried the following but it didn't do anything.

```
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

.

.

.

\appendix

\captionsetup{list=no}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I guess `\caption*` should do just that.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. You can indent code sections by 4 spaces or equivalently highlight them and use the `{}` button, as I just did. Also it helps if you could make your example a complete small document that shows the problem, rather than just a fragment that can not be run.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? It's important to know what's your setup, because with the standard classes your method works.

Answer (score 3):

if the document class you use includes all captions (or all `*`'ed titles) in the contents, you can manually put a line in the appropriate contents list to suppress it.

here's what has been devised for use with the ams document classes.  add a definition in the preamble:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SkipTocEntry}[4]{}
```

(if you're using `hyperref`, change the `4` to `5` -- different number of arguments.)

then, just before the command that will write to the `toc` file (or `lot` or `lof`) the line that you don't want, insert the instruction to suppress it:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\SkipTocEntry}
```

i'm not sure that this has actually been used inside a float, but it's worth a try.

in the ams author-faq, there's an entry that covers this in somewhat more detail, although it's written from the point of view of chapter and section headings.  go to [the faq](http://www.ams.org/authors/faq/author-faq) and search for "omit".  the title of the relevant entry is "How can I omit or change a heading in the table of contents?"; click on it to expand the text.  here is [a more compact way of reaching this answer](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=238); look for the red box surrounding the item.

when i have access once more to a working system, i'll try this with figure and table captions, and update the faq as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you Barbara. I did your suggestion. It removed the appendix table from the list of table but instead it added "10pt". How can I remove that "10pt".

Comment: @HA -- this sounds like the `\SkipTocEntry` is removing one more "argument" than intended.  but to really be able to figure out what is happening, a real minimal working example is needed, or at least the document class being used.  with the `book` or `report` class, the command `\captionsetup{list=no}` is sufficient.

Comment: @HA If it works, you should considering acknowledging the effort put in by barbara by clicking "this answer is useful".