# Remove individual entries from List of Tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

This is my first post here, so the TeX code may not appear as desired, but I'll do what I can to provide a MWE.

I want to be able to suppress the appearance of individual figures/tables in the list of figures/tables. There are several approaches out there, but none of them seem to work for me because I'm using a non-standard document class which does not allow the use of the `caption` package, or the `longtable` package (packages load OK, but do not function as expected, or, really, at all). However, I still need to have tables that span multiple pages, which I have enter code here done manually by defining where the page break should be as a new table, controlling float placement, and redefining how the figures are numbered (as well as resetting the counter). So, having done it manually, each table appears in the list of tables, but I want to explicitly suppress the appearance of the second part of that table, defined as its own table in this case. Also, I can't use the `\caption*` command because the tables must be numbered in the text (it's a thesis—lots of special formatting requirements).

So, the MWE (note that I am using a standard document class in MWE so that it's universally workable, but I cannot use the `caption` or `longtable` package) is below. How do I delete the second table from the List of Tables?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\begin{document}


\listoftables

\newpage

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{table}{0}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
table & of & data \\
with & many & lines \\
\end{tabular}
\caption[LoT Caption for Example Table, part 1]{Caption that appears with Table, Part 1}
\end{table}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}, \textit{continued}}
\setcounter{table}{0}

\clearpage

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
part & 2 & of table \\
table & of & data \\
with & many & lines \\
\end{tabular}
\caption[LoT Caption for Example Table, part 2]{Caption that appears with Table, Part 2}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Note: I did find a workaround, which I have been using, but I would like something cleaner (less labor-intensive for each compilation). The workaround is to modify the `file.lot` file, deleting the lines that correspond to the tables I want to remove from the LoT. Since this changes the number of pages of the LoT, I then have to recompile, redelete the lines from file.lot, and recompile again. Making the `file.lot` read-only (as suggested by another user in another thread) prevents the page numbers from readjusting to the proper numbers after the change in the length of the LoT, so these lines have to be deleted from file.lot each time the document is compiled.

Comment: So you want "0.1, *continued*" in the list of tables or nothing at all? However, if you can't use the `caption` package, you shouldn't be using `floatrow` that loads it.

Comment: similar question: [How to exclude an appendix table from list of table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103512/)

Comment: No, I can't use longtable. The package loads without error, but does not introduce page breaks mid-table the way it does in standard document classes. So I'm not getting an error message, but the behavior of the page breaks seems to be controlled differently in this atypical class file.

Comment: I ideally want nothing at all in the List of Tables. Thank you for the note about Floatrow also loading caption. I was able to use the Caption package (see answer thread, below), but the tools to toggle the listing of tables in the list of tables (`\captionsetup[table]{list=no}`) doesn't actually modulate the listings that appear in the list of tables (but does compile without error messages). Possibly something strange with the class file?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
\caption[]{Caption that appears with Table, Part 2}
```

Comment: That suppresses the text that appears with the table in the list of tables, but it does not suppress the entry itself. I wanted to be able to suppress the whole entry, since the two tables aren't left-justified in the LoT when I add the 'continued' to the table number

Comment: sure. I thought that you wanted only the word continued. However, it looks like a bug in `floatrow`, because it works when loading only package `caption`

Comment: I think it may be more likely a bug in the class file that I was provided with ... I forced the caption package to replace the floatrow package (using `\usepackage{caption}` and `\captionoptions[table]{position=above}`), but the unwanted entries in the LoT remained when I used `\caption[]{caption placed here only}`. Ah, well. At least there's a workaround, even if it's labor-intensive.

Comment: In my test case I get no entry!

Comment: @Herbert I had a similar situation and tried your solution. It partially works, in that it adds extra vertical space between two LoF entries. I have posted a question with MWE [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331868/78565), please have a look.